# git status shows the current directory as untracked

Tags: git, github-actions

I am using a GitHub Action running Linux to build my CMake project.
After cloning the branch and setting up the environment, git status is clean, but at the end of the build git status shows:

```
On branch XXX
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/XXX'.

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
    ./
```

Why would the current directory show as untracked and how do I avoid that and keep the status clean?

Comment: This question would benefit from a [mcve]. Can you show us the github action that is resulting in this behavior?

Comment: Have you accounted for all the build artifacts e.g. objects files, binaries, precompiled headers, etc. generated during your build?

Comment: @larsks while trying to come up with a minimal example I realized I can get to the same state locally if I repeat the steps performed in the GitHub action, see my update.

Answer (score -1):

See the update to the question - turns out it was an issue with my .gitignore file.

Comment: Do not update the question to include the answer. Put the answer in the Answer field. Or just delete the whole thing.